# how to show <span color=#f00000;> data on textview in android with color?

Tags: android, html, webview

Actually my problem is that i have data that comes from webservice,i parse that data and fill in my sqlite databases rows.The data contain some html tags that android does not support like

```
> <span Style="color:#ff0000;">the Lord Is The Creator <span>;
```

So "The Lord Is the Creator" will be shown in red color.like this i have textviews in ListView in android.the Html.fromHtml also not working.
**Any Help is appriciated.**

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.fromHtml();
```

This function returns a Spanned object wich can be set as text for a Textview.

Comment: not sure the style attribute is interpreted by fromHtml, though?

Comment: but it does not show color.The text is shown in normal color.but the span have red color.

Answer (score 0):

If your concerns is only show the textview with color in list view then only store hexa color of item in sqlite.

And at the time of showing textview in listview use textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

Comment: but span is only tag i have many HTML tags like bold italc but all they are resolved by using **HTML.fromhtml()** but the span tag not working any different idea.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by njzk2, the style attribute is not interpreted by [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29). The other workaround could be to make some server side changes. Like the string from the server could be something like

```
"<font color='red'>the Lord Is The Creator</font>."
```

and then you could use it like this

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>the Lord Is The Creator</font>."));
```

Comment: the server side changes are not possible.I have a trick but i dnt know it owrk or not.If a change the place of **Span** to **font** and remove the style tag the it should work or not????

Comment: Its not **span** that is causing the issue, its **Style**. Maybe you could have a parsing algo that parses through your text, and then replaces span by font and also adds the color.